# Jquery Slider Timer

Tags: jquery, timer, slider

I need to create a custom slider for a website using jquery. So far, I've managed to make it behave the way I want it if I click a button, but I would like to implement an automatic timer, so that the slides will switch after 5 seconds.

Here is my JS code:

```
function MasterSlider() {
    //store the current button ID
    var current_button = $(this).attr('id');

    //reset all the items
    $('#slider ul a').removeClass('slider-button-active');         
    //set current item as active
    $(this).addClass('slider-button-active');


    //scroll it to the right position
    $('.mask').scrollTo($(this).attr('rel'), 850);


    //Check which button is pressed and fade the text accordingly
    if(current_button == "slider_item1")
    {
        $('#slider h3').fadeOut().removeClass('caption_active');
        $('#slider_caption1').fadeIn().addClass('caption_active');
    }
    else if(current_button == "slider_item2")
    {
        $('#slider h3').fadeOut().removeClass('caption_active');
        $('#slider_caption2').fadeIn().addClass('caption_active');
    }
    else if(current_button == "slider_item3")
    {
        $('#slider h3').fadeOut().removeClass('caption_active');
        $('#slider_caption3').fadeIn().addClass('caption_active');      
    }

    //disable click event
       return false;      
}

//append click event to the UL list anchor tag
$('#slider ul a').click(MasterSlider);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically trigger `click()` on your `a` elements in a `setInterval` !

```
var intv;
var current = 0;  // STARTING SLIDE(<li>element button) INDEX
var slN = $('#slider li').length; // get number of slides(buttons.. all the same)


 // your function here with
 // clearInterval(intv);
 // in the second line.
 // In third line put:
 // current = $(this).closest('li').index();

// AUTO SLIDE

function auto(){
   intv = setInterval(function() {
        $('#slider ul li').eq( current++%slN  ).find('a').click();
   }, 5000 );       
}
auto(); // to start immediately auto-slide

// PAUSE ON MOUSEOVER

$('#slider').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
    var onMouEnt = e.type=='mouseenter' ? clearInterval(intv) : auto() ;
});
```

- Thanks to `current++%slN` the `auto` function will loop once the last button is triggered
- The PAUSE thing detects events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` over your gallery and uses a ternary operator to do:

```
$('#slider').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){ // catch eVENT
    var onMouEnt = e.type=='mouseenter' ?  // if e IS mouseenter
                   clearInterval(intv) :   // clear autoslide interval
                   auto() ;                // else (is mouseleave) run 'auto' fn
});
```

Comment: Hello roXon,

Thanks for the fast reply.

I updated my slider according to your instructions, but it jumps directly to slide 3 and stops there, doing nothing else. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: @DragosIonescu if you setup a jsBin demo I can take a look

Answer (score -1):

There is is a function setInterval

```
    function hi(){
        //Your code here
    }

    //set an interval
    setInterval(hi, 30000);
```