# First image of slideshow does not load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've just started with CSS and JavaScript, and I tried to make an image slider by looking into w3schools. The slider works, but the first image always comes empty only with the navigation bars being visible.but once I click the next button, it works fine.I'm not understanding what to change with this. Here's the code.

```js
'use strict';
var slideIndex = 1;

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  //alert('showslides('+ n +')\nslideIndex='+slideIndex);
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n === undefined) {
    n = ++slideIndex;
  }
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";

  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <?php
        include './p1.php';
        // put your code here
        ?>
    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="pics/bali2.jpg" height="400px" width="800px">
        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="pics/brazil1.jpg" height="400px" width="800px">
        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="pics/germany.jpg" height="400px" width="800px">
        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
      </div>

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Array index starts from `0` and not `1`.

Comment: Hi, even I thought the same and tried replacing it with 0, but its still the same..the first image doesnt load, but it loads after i click the next button

Comment: @MichaelMontero In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic change pictures in slideshow with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969385/automatic-change-pictures-in-slideshow-with-jquery)

Comment: There's a much similar solution [here related to slide-show and different ways.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969385/automatic-change-pictures-in-slideshow-with-jquery/51969929#51969929)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The slider works, but the first image always comes empty only with the navigation bars being visible

Just because of you apply css this `mySlides` on your, so your all div not visble. When you are click on `next` or `previous` or `slider` so particular container are showing.

So you need to apply the `style="display: block;"` on your first div.

**DEMO**

```js
var slideIndex = 1,
    interval;

function stopAndStart() {
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
    interval = setInterval(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds;
}

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    stopAndStart()
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    stopAndStart()
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i,
        slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"),
        dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    if (n === undefined) {
        n = ++slideIndex;
    }
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}

stopAndStart();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background: burlywood;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="display: block;">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/555985/fff&text=1">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/555985/fff&text=2">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/555985/fff&text=3">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: hello! It worked! thank you so much! although the "if condition" within the startandStop function doesn't work properly for me..adding setInterval in the other functions worked. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Yes I in my solution have `setInterval`. You can check. If solution help you so you can click on right icon to accept the answer.